# Remove "by ShieldUI"?

Tags: shieldui

I am not sure where this gets added to the footer of my grid.

```
by ShieldUIDemo Version
```

I am using the version for non-profits.

How do I remove it?

Comment: If you are going to downvote the question, at least be man enough to say why. That is the biggest thing I hate about SO in that people can hide behind their downvotes.

Comment: I am using ShieldUI Non Profit version NOT the Trial Version and I also have this when using their sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those labels are shown only for the Trial versions of ShieldUI.

If you are part of a non-profit organization, you should be eligible a Free for Non-commercial license from them [here](https://www.shieldui.com/free-for-non-commercial-request).

Comment: Just purchased commercial version

Comment: The question stated MB34 was already using the Non-Profit version.